# How to use jQuery sortable to update div ID's when a user moves an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery sortable to allow users to move elements around on a page. Each div element has a unique ID. When the user swaps an element on the page with another I want to also swap those element ID's and alert the new list of ID's order, So I can save this new order to the backend.

I am struggling to get the child element ID's for when the user moves an element. My jQuery so far is:

```
  $(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
      stop: function(ev, ui) {
        var children = $('#sortable').sortable('refreshPositions').children();
        alert('Positions: ');
        $.each(children, function() {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
      }
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
    var drag_id = $('.container').attr("id");
  });
```

but the alert message is always `undefined`. How do I swap the div ID's when the user makes a change and save this to an array and then `alert` this array?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kevinabraham/7rbv20yd/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set ID for `li` tag:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
      stop: function(ev, ui) {
        var children = $('#sortable').sortable('refreshPositions').children();
        alert('Positions: ');
        $.each(children, function() {
          alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
      }
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
    var drag_id = $('.container').attr("id");
});
```

Check Fiddle now:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7rbv20yd/5/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solves the alert issue but doesn't swap the `ID`'s of the <`li>` when moved.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7rbv20yd/6/ check this will create ID's in sequence

Answer (score 1):

The following code or will be helpful?

```
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    stop: function(ev, ui) {
      var children = $('#sortable').sortable('refreshPositions').find(".container");

      $.each(children, function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
      });
    }
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
  var drag_id = $('.container').attr("id");
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @kamiya55. This fixes the alert issue. But doesn't swap the ID's of the elements? For example `<div id="container1">1</div>` in position `1` swaps with `<div id="container4" class="container">4</div>` in position 4. Updated code should be: `<div id="container1">4</div>` `<div id="container4" class="container">1</div>`